# Extra white space at bottom, not padding, or margin, in Safari, what is it?

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css, safari

I am working on a project for a website, and I have come across a strange error.

**The Build and the Problem**

My website I'm building contains transitions, and slide up effects, which look and work as they are supposed to. They work properly everywhere else until you hit Safari and Safari IOS on the iPhone. What happens then is as you scroll down there is this tremendous amount of white space at the bottom of the screen it is neither padding, nor margin that can be identified by the inspector. So I'm a bit lost.

**Attempted Fixes**

I have googled this issue and search around, and found a few things, but they do not work.

My first attempt was:

```
*{
    -webkit-padding-end: 0 !important;
}
```

nothing... Then I tried

```
html, body{
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
}
```

It looked promising but again nothing. So I am at a loss.

This is only exhibited on Safari or an iPhone. Your scroll speed does not matter.

Comment: it's probably your overflow-x scroll bar, you have overflow set to scroll on the body. change it to overflow-y:scroll; and that will get rid of the one at the bottom

Comment: @RachelGallen   that did not work

Comment: did you reload the page and clear your cache?

Comment: i just looked at the page and you didn't even make the change

Comment: I worked it on my localhost, I have not pushed it up to the test website quite yet

Comment: You should make that change anyway, you don't need/want a horizontal scroll, it's unnecessary and unsightly

Comment: I figured as much, so I'm just going to use it as is XD. Any other suggestions, because this is a very awkward problem, and I don't want it to launch with the error?

Comment: make the first fix , then i'll have another look

Answer (score 0):

Would most likely have to do with window height being referred to incorrectly in Safari on mobile. Try setting the height dynamically, using window.innerHeight with some js, instead of resorting to height: 100vh or 100%. Fix: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/2414